# Tab content dissapearing

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a very specific question that I cannot figure out for the death of me. 
On this site: http://www.telcogreen.com.au/voice_new

For some reason the content of tab 3 dissapears if I add secondary set of tabs in tab 2. However, if I reverse them, I can have secondary tabs on 3 and the ones on 4 will still display. It's just tab 2 that causes the issue.

Can somebody please point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: you really should post pertinent code here on the site. or at least point to a page where the problem is actually occurring. otherwise how could anyone possibly help you?

Comment: Does a black rectangle mean an error?

Comment: @Funk Doc - I've posted a link to where the problem is. Taking just the tabs code from there an putting it here it would not help at all. There's simply too much code there, with all the scripts, and dependencies and the actual html. That's where you can see it in action exactly as it is, you can inspect the elements to see there's actually content in that tab, etc.

Comment: @Banzay - no, that is part of the page. The actual content of the tab does not show. If you inspect it you will see it there, but it does not show. For some reason if there are secondary tabs inside the second tab content, clicking on the third tab does not append  the class that makes visible the third tab content. However, the same behavior does not happen between the third and the fourth tabs (or subsequent)

Comment: Why do you link two scripts `cbpFWTabs.js` and `cbpFWTabs1.js`, those are having a similar content?

Comment: Found one more huge mistake. You declared `<div id='tabs1'>` twice. `id` has to be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that 3rd section doesn't render, because you try to bind click to wrong selector.
Here is your code:

```
/***** voice page hosted c*/
    $('a.hosted').bind('click', function () {
        $('#tabs ul li').removeClass('tab-current');

        $('#hosted').parents('li').addClass('tab-current');

        $('#section-1').removeClass('content-current');
        $('#section-3').addClass('content-current');

        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 570 }, "slow");

        return false;
    });
```

There are no `a` tags with neither class nor id `hosted` in the rest of markup.
And I would (if using jquery 1.9.1) get rid of `.bind()` handler. You use `.bind()` method, which is a little deprecated. I think it's better to write `$('_selector_').click(function () {...` instead of `$('_selector_').bind('click', function () {...`  And I'd consider an idea of replacing `addClass...removeClass...addClass...removeClass` chains with `toggleClass`.
Anyway, if you want find out what is wrong, learn debugger and watch a breakpoints. 
Here is a objects tree of your tabs on the pic:
[image]